# How to mock returncode, stdout, stderr from subprocess.run with pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, subprocess, pytest

I am trying to write unit tests with pytest to mock `subprocess.run` call following some other examples on here, but running into difficulty. I have the following class:

```
class Bmx:

    def version(self) -> Tuple[int, int, int]:
        cmd = [self.exec_path, '-v']
        err, out = self._run(cmd)
        version = re.search(r'v\d+\.\d+\.\d+', out, re.IGNORECASE)[0][1:].split('.')
        return int(version[0]), int(version[1]), int(version[2])

    @staticmethod
    def _run(cmd: List[str], shell: bool = False) -> Tuple[str, str]:
        proc = subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shell, universal_newlines=True)
        if proc.returncode > 0:
            raise BmxError(proc.stderr)
        return proc.stderr, proc.stdout
```

I tried to write a unit test for the `version` method as follows:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

import pytest

from pybmx.bmx import Bmx


@patch('pybmx.bmx.subprocess.run')
def test_version(mock_run):
    mock_proc = MagicMock()
    mock_proc.configure_mock(**{
        'returncode.return_value': 0,
        'stdout.return_value': 'raw2bmx, bmx v1.1.6, Mar  3 2023 10:02:28 (scm v1.1-6-g43fac95-dirty)'
    })
    mock_run.return_value = mock_proc
    assert Bmx('raw2bmx').version() == (1, 1, 6)
```

However the test fails with the following:

```
    @staticmethod
    def _run(cmd: List[str], shell: bool = False) -> Tuple[str, str]:
        proc = subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=shell, universal_newlines=True)
>       if proc.returncode > 0:
E       TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
```

I thought that by configuring the `returncode.return_value` using the MagicMock `configure` method I would be mocking the return code, but it seems I am not understanding this correctly. I'm also wondering if there is a way to achieve this with `pytest` rather than `unittest`. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `mock_proc.configure_mock(**{"f.return_value": ...})`
is for mocking methods but `proc.returncode` is an attribute.
Mocking attributes is even easier, though (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock)):

```py
>>> m = MagicMock(attribute=3, other='fish')
>>> m.attribute
3
>>> m.other
'fish'
```